# Can Force.com - App subscription user can access (Read - Write) Lead , Quote and Opportunity?

Tags: force.com

I have users that needed to access Lead , Opportunity and Quote and I have a permission set that gives only read access to force.com - app subscription license user but while assigning permission sets gives below error

"Dean Neudorf dean@moversalliance.ca Force.com - App Subscription Can't assign permission set SalesAgentForce.comUser to user Dean Neudorf. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read Leads"

Answer (score 1):

Correct, that license doesn't have leads or oppty.  Permission sets won't get around it, so that the cause for the error.